# How do I identify how many reactions are occurring when precipitating a mixture?

Tags: stoichiometry, mixtures

An example of a question is:

> After dissolving $x$ grams of a mixture of $\ce{Na2SO4}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$ in water, you add an excess of $\ce{BaCl2}$ solution. You filter off the precipitate which forms, dry it, and find that it weighs $y$ grams. What is the percent by mass of $\ce{Na2SO4}$ in the original mixture?"

If I am correct, the reaction for this would be:
$$\ce{BaCl2 + Na2SO4 + NaCl -> BaSO4 + 3NaCl}$$

However, there are some questions which are of the same format but have two separate reactions:

> A $x$ gram mixture of $\ce{CaCl2}$ and $\ce{RbCl}$ is dissolved in water. Addition of $\ce{AgNO3}$ causes the chloride ion to precipitate as $\ce{AgCl}$. The mass of $\ce{AgCl}$ collected is $y$. What is the percent by mass of $\ce{RbCl}$ in the original mixture?

For this one, would the reaction be two equations?

\begin{align}
\ce{CaCl2 + AgNO3 &-> Ca(NO3)2 + 2AgCl}\\
\ce{RbCl + AgNO3 &-> RbNO3 + AgCl}
\end{align}

I know how to do these types of questions past the point of deciding whether or not there are two equations. I just don't understand why I couldn't write that last one as a single equation, in the same way as I did the first example. Could anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945).

Comment: You could: Ag+ + Cl- -> AgCl

Answer (score 1):

You asked two very different questions.

> **(1) How do I identify how many reactions are occurring when precipitating a mixture?**

There is no information in way the reactants are shown in a chemical equation as to what the products will be. That is to say that you have to know the products of the reaction.

> **(2) For this one, would the reaction be two equations?**

Chemists use shorthand all the time. Reactions are typically netted out to the pertinent aspect under consideration. However if I were writing the reactions for the second problem I'd do it much differently that you have presented. I think I'd write:

\begin{align}
x\ce{CaCl2} + y\ce{RbCl &->} x\ce{Ca^2+} + y\ce{Rb+} + (x+y)\ce{Cl-}\\
x\ce{Ca^2+} + y\ce{Rb+} + (x+y)\ce{Cl-} &\ce{->[excess AgNO3]} x\ce{Ca^2+} + y\ce{Rb+} + (x+y)\ce{AgCl v}\\
\end{align}

From an analytical chemistry perspective there are two steps. First the chloride salts are dissolved and then the silver nitrate is added. You wouldn't want to add the salts to a silver nitrate solution since the silver chloride could coat the Ca and Rb salts preventing a complete reaction.

I even might write the second reaction as:

$$ (x+y)\ce{Cl-} \ce{->[excess AgNO3]} (x+y)\ce{AgCl v}$$

I'm not a fan of one line jobs like:

$$x\ce{CaCl2} + y\ce{RbCl ->} x\ce{Ca^2+} + y\ce{Rb+} + (x+y)\ce{Cl-} \ce{->[excess AgNO3]} (x+y)\ce{AgCl v}$$